# CannotLoadObjectTypeException in Spring.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, spring.net

I'm using spring.net 1.3.1 in a asp.net 3.5 project in vs 2010. I'm not doing any kind of mvc stuff; I needed Spring to create and manipulate objects.

I've followed the documentation, added Spring.Core and Spring.Web dlls reference  my web.config is like this:

```
   <sectionGroup name="spring">
    <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler, Spring.Web"/>
    <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>

  </sectionGroup> 
   <system.web>
     <httpModules>
        <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
     </httpModules>
     <!-- no spring confi in httpHandlers-->
  </system.web>
   <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="~/config/clients.xml" />
    </context>
  </spring>
```

in clients.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net"> 
  <object id="CAL"  type="myrouter.clientcode.CAL, myrouter.clientcode"/>  
</objects>
```

in Defaults.aspx.cs

```
  IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
  CAL calobject = (CAL)ctx.GetObject("CAL");
```

i'm getting

> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type from string value 'myrouter.clientcode.CAL, myrouter.clientcode'.]
>      Spring.Core.TypeResolution.TypeResolver.Resolve(String typeName) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeResolution\TypeResolver.cs:81
>      Spring.Core.TypeResolution.GenericTypeResolver.Resolve(String typeName) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeResolution\GenericTypeResolver.cs:97
>      Spring.Core.TypeResolution.CachedTypeResolver.Resolve(String typeName) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeResolution\CachedTypeResolver.cs:107
>      Spring.Core.TypeResolution.TypeResolutionUtils.ResolveType(String typeName) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeResolution\TypeResolutionUtils.cs:106
>      Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectDefinition.ResolveObjectType() in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractObjectDefinition.cs:640
>      Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.ResolveObjectType(RootObjectDefinition rod, String objectName) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractObjectFactory.cs:1096
>   [CannotLoadObjectTypeException: Cannot resolve type [myrouter.clientcode.CAL, myrouter.clientcode] for object with name 'CAL' defined in file [D:\WORK\visual studio\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myrouter\myrouter\config\clients.xml] line 3]
>      Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.ResolveObjectType(RootObjectDefinition rod, String objectName) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\AbstractObjectFactory.cs:1100
>      Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory.PreInstantiateSingletons() in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Objects\Factory\Support\DefaultListableObjectFactory.cs:472
>      Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.Refresh() in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\AbstractApplicationContext.cs:1017
>      Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext..ctor(WebApplicationContextArgs args) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebApplicationContext.cs:125
>      Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext..ctor(String name, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] configurationLocations) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebApplicationContext.cs:82
>      _dynamic_Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext..ctor(Object[] ) +242
>      Spring.Reflection.Dynamic.SafeConstructor.Invoke(Object[] arguments) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Reflection\Dynamic\DynamicConstructor.cs:116
>      Spring.Context.Support.RootContextInstantiator.InvokeContextConstructor(ConstructorInfo ctor) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:563
>      Spring.Context.Support.ContextInstantiator.InstantiateContext() in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:508
>      Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.InstantiateContext(IApplicationContext parentContext, Object configContext, String contextName, Type contextType, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] resources) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:351
>      Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler.InstantiateContext(IApplicationContext parent, Object configContext, String contextName, Type contextType, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] resources) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebContextHandler.cs:129
>      Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.Create(Object parent, Object configContext, XmlNode section) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Context\Support\ContextHandler.cs:289
>   [ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating context 'spring.root': Could not load type from string value 'myrouter.clientcode.CAL, myrouter.clientcode'.]
>      System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult) +202
>      System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject) +1061
>      System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject) +1431
>      System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission) +56
>      System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey) +8
>      System.Web.HttpContext.GetSection(String sectionName) +47
>      System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetSection(String sectionName) +39
>    System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String configKey) +6
>      System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName) +78
>      Spring.Util.ConfigurationUtils.GetSection(String sectionName) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Util\ConfigurationUtils.cs:71
>      Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext.GetContextInternal(String virtualPath) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebApplicationContext.cs:335
>      Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext.GetRootContext() in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebApplicationContext.cs:223
>      Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule.Init(HttpApplication app) in c:_svn\spring-net\tags\spring-net-1.3.1\src\Spring\Spring.Web\Context\Support\WebSupportModule.cs:175
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +65
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModules() +43
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +729
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +298
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +107
>      System.Web

Sorry for this long post; I wanted to be as precised as possible and give as much as information that I could. I think I'm missing something but just can't figure out what. Is the `HttpHandler` a must in spring.net configuration in asp.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this issue is the result of some error in your

```
<object id="CAL"  type="myrouter.clientcode.CAL, myrouter.clientcode"/>
```

configuration.

Check/verify the following:

- the namespace *myrouter.clientcode* is really where the *CAL* class exists
- the assembly that contains this type is really *myrouter.clientcode*
- these namespaces and assembly names match in re: case-sensitivity as well

Comment: +1 the very first line of the exception message says so...
"Could not load type from string value 'myrouter.clientcode.CAL, myrouter.clientcode'."
Are you sure that the assembly name is 'myrouter.clientcode' ?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i got it fixed.i used the wrong assembly info.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. what was wrong in your assembly info?